# AddOrUpdate violates unique index

Tags: entity-framework

I'm writing an MVC app in ASP.NET with the help of EF and I'm trying to seed my database. I have the following model:

```
public class Team
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentTeam")]
    public int? ParentTeamId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Cannot create a Team without a name")]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Members { get; set; }

    public virtual Team ParentTeam { get; set; }

    public Team() { }

    public Team(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

My migration says:

```
var team = new Team("Admin");
var team2 = new Team("Test Team");
var team3 = new Team("Test Team 2");
context.Teams.AddOrUpdate(t => t.Name, team, team2, team3);
context.SaveChanges();
```

And then, when I run `Update-Database`, I get:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in
>   object 'dbo.Teams' with unique index 'IX_Name'. The duplicate key
>   value is (Admin).

It's a little confusing - I thought I told `AddOrUpdate` to identify rows to update by their names, but this does not happen. I cannot add `Name` to `Team`'s primary key, because it has a self-referencing foreign key (I could add `ParentTeamName` as a property, but I don't feel that it should be necessary). Am I misunderstanding the behaviour of `AddOrUpdate`? Did I specify the condition wrong?

Comment: I cant repeat the problem with EF 6.2.0  The tables populate correctly in the seed with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same reason. In my case, it was working fine, until I needed to use an Unique Index, when it broke.

My solution was to create a `CustomAddOrUpdate` method where I try to find the existing instance first based on a `Where predicate`. If I find it, I just update the properties and if not, it is added to the context.

However, before updating the instance, I had to copy the key values from the original instance to the new instance, to avoid an EF exception telling you cannot change key properties.

Here are the code snippets:

1) First the code in the context class

```
public void CustomAddOrUpdate<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> whereExpression, TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
{
    var entitySet = this.EntitySet<TEntity>();
    var foundInstance = entitySet.Where(whereExpression).FirstOrDefault();
    if (foundInstance != null)
    {
        CopyKeyProperties<TEntity>(foundInstance, entity);
        Entry(foundInstance).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
    }
    else
    {
        entitySet.Add(entity);
    }
}

private void CopyKeyProperties<TEntity>(TEntity source, TEntity target) where TEntity : class
{
    string[] keys = this.GetKeyNames<TEntity>();
    foreach(var keyName in keys)
    {
        Entry(target).Property(keyName).CurrentValue = Entry(source).Property(keyName).CurrentValue;
    }
}
```

2) Then on my seed code:

```
    var entityList = new List<MyExempleEntity>() 
    { 
        new MyExampleEntity { Prop1 = "a p1", Prop2 = "a p2" },
        new MyExampleEntity { Prop1 = "b p1", Prop2 = "b p2" },
        new MyExampleEntity { Prop1 = "c p1", Prop2 = "c p2" },
    }
    foreach(var item in entityList)
    {
        context.CustomAddOrUpdate<MyExampleEntity>(x => x.Prop1 == item.Prop1 && x.Prop2 == item.Prop2, item);
    }
    context.SaveChanges()
```

3) And to wrap up, here you are the code to get the KeyProperties from an entity:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;

namespace System.Data.Entity
{
    public static class DbContextExtensions
    {
        public static string[] GetKeyNames<TEntity>(this DbContext context)
            where TEntity : class
        {
            return context.GetKeyNames(typeof(TEntity));
        }

        public static string[] GetKeyNames(this DbContext context, Type entityType)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            }

            MetadataWorkspace metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;

            // Get the mapping between CLR types and metadata OSpace
            var objectItemCollection = ((ObjectItemCollection)metadata.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.OSpace));

            // Get metadata for given CLR type
            var entityMetadata = metadata
                    .GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace)
                    .Single(e => objectItemCollection.GetClrType(e) == entityType);

            return entityMetadata.KeyProperties.Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code was grabbed from this blog: 
https://romiller.com/2014/10/07/ef6-1-getting-key-properties-for-an-entity/